# Use groovy script output as input for another groovy script

Tags: groovy

I'll apologise in advance, I'm new to groovy. The problem I have is I have 3 groovy scripts which perform different functionality, and I need to call them from my main groovy script, using the output from script 1 as input for script 2 and script 2's output as input for script 3.

I've tried the following code:

```
script = new GroovyShell(binding)
script.run(new File("script1.groovy"), "--p",  "$var" ) | script.run(new File("script2.groovy"), "<",  "$var" )
```

When I run the above code the first script runs successfully but the 2nd doesn't run at all.

Script 1 takes an int as a parameter using the `"--p",  "$var"` code. This runs successfully in the main script using: `script.run(new File("script1.groovy"), "--p",  "$var" )` - Script 1's output is an xml file.

When I run `script.run(new File("script2.groovy"), "<",  "$var" )` on its own in the main groovy script nothing happens and the system hangs.

I can run script 2 from the command line using `groovy script2.groovy < input_file` and it works fine.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot pass the `<` as an argument to the script as redirection is handled by the Shell when you run things from the command line...

Redirecting output from Scripts into other scripts is notoriously difficult, and basically relies on you changing `System.out` for the duration of each script (and hoping that nothing else in the JVM prints and messes up your data)

Better to use java processes like the following:

Given these 3 scripts:

#### script1.groovy

```
// For each argument
args.each {
  // Wrap it in xml and write it out
  println "<woo>$it</woo>"
}
```

#### linelength.groovy

```
// read input
System.in.eachLine { line ->
  // Write out the number of chars in each line
  println line.length()
}
```

#### pretty.groovy

```
// For each line print out a nice report
int index = 1
System.in.eachLine { line ->
  println "Line $index contains $line chars (including the <woo></woo> bit)"
  index++
}
```

We can then write something like this to get a new groovy process to run each in turn, and pipe the outputs into each other (using the overloaded `or` [operator on Process](http://groovy.codehaus.org/groovy-jdk/java/lang/Process.html#or%28java.lang.Process%29)):

```
def s1 = 'groovy script1.groovy arg1 andarg2'.execute()
def s2 = 'groovy linelength.groovy'.execute()
def s3 = 'groovy pretty.groovy'.execute()

// pipe the output of process1 to process2, and the output
// of process2 to process3
s1 | s2 | s3

s3.waitForProcessOutput( System.out, System.err )
```

Which prints out:

```
Line 1 contains 15 chars (including the <woo></woo> bit)
Line 2 contains 18 chars (including the <woo></woo> bit)
```

Comment: Thanks for the solutoion could I just ask 2 things about the solution:

Comment: 1: when running the first script the args will be coming from a list so they will change each time so in your solution is it possible to specify the arg as $arg or is that syntax illegal for use with the solution.

Comment: 2 - When using the output of script 1 as input for script 2 - Script 2 is designed so the user can specify input so to specify an input file when calling the script from a command line you would use script2 < inputFile or if passing in an arg : script2 --p arg (the arg would be an int). So when piping the output of 1 script as input to another script in this situation is the flag needed or will the pipe over-ride the need for a flag.

Comment: For 1: `def s1 = "groovy script1.groovy ${args.join( ' ' )}".execute()` For 2: it should work as-is (I think)

Answer (score 0):

```
//store standard I/O
PrintStream systemOut = System.out
InputStream systemIn = System.in
//Buffer for exchanging data between scripts
ByteArrayOutputStream buffer = new ByteArrayOutputStream()
PrintStream out = new PrintStream(buffer)
//Redirecting "out" of 1st stream to buffer
System.out = out
//RUN 1st script
evaluate("println 'hello'")
out.flush()
//Redirecting buffer to "in" of 2nd script
System.in = new ByteArrayInputStream(buffer.toByteArray())
//set standard "out"
System.out = systemOut
//RUN 2nd script
evaluate("println 'message from the first script: ' + new Scanner(System.in).next()")
//set standard "in"
System.in = systemIn
```

result is: 'message from the first script: hello'